# Paths with -a does not make sense for bash function

Tags: git

Here is my bash function.

```
push() {
> cd /var/www/html/wp
> git init
> git add *
> git commit -am  $1
> git push -f origin master
> }
```

I want to execute it.

```
debian8@hwy:$push 'to delete file test'       
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /var/www/html/wp/.git/        
fatal: Paths with -a does not make sense.
```

How to fix my bash function push?

The below commands can be executed successfully after **rm /var/www/html/wp/test**

```
 cd /var/www/html/wp
 git init
 git add *
 git commit -am  'to delete file test'
 git push -f origin master
```

I just want to write a bash function push to add parameter,to run it such as

```
push  'to delete file test'
```

To let push function as

```
 push(){
 cd /var/www/html/wp
 git init
 git add *
 git commit -am $1
 git push -f origin master
 }
```

Comment: No it is not a git issue.

Comment: **git commit -am  'to delete file test'** is verified,it can execute successfully.

Comment: @MartinSerrano: technically, it is a Bash issue (or, rather, a shell issue), since the problem occurs because of a lack of quotes around the parameter expansion.

Comment: Please be kindly and friendly to me as giusti do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like `$1` is expanding into several arguments, and Git is taking the first one to be the commit message and the remainder as files. Guard `"$1"` into quotes.

But I must add that there are several problems with that script. It's very unsafe. You are executing several commands without checking once for success or if the input is appropriate. Doing that and forcing a Git push can give you big headache later on.

Comment: My target is simple----to git push my wordpress directory everyday.

Answer (score 0):

Note: with Git 2.22 (Q2 2019), you will actually see *which* "path (in your case the `$1` value) does not make sense.
The message given when "`git commit -a <paths>`" errors out has been updated.

See [commit 5a1dbd4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5a1dbd48bcd1b917ce103e4f5bb68d3cfadf9543) (20 Mar 2019) by [Nguyễn Thái Ngọc Duy (`pclouds`)](https://github.com/pclouds).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit e313c76](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e313c768e0daf78da2d9e23967dc6625e9db0837), 25 Apr 2019)</sup>

> ### `commit`: improve error message in "`-a <paths>`" case
>
> I did something stupid today and got
>
> ```
> $ git commit -a --fixup= @^
> fatal: Paths with -a does not make sense.
> ```
>
> which didn't make any sense (at least for the first few seconds).
>
> Include the first path(spec) in the error message to help spot the
>   problem quicker. Now it shows
>
> ```
> fatal: paths '@^ ...' with -a does not make sense
> ```
>
> which should ring some bell because @^ should clearly not be considered
>   a path.