# git error when trying to create bash script "fatal: Paths with -a does not make sense."

Tags: bash, git

I'm trying to create a git script cause I'm sick of the workflow and headaches that come with if I forget something.

I've looked at this

[Paths with -a does not make sense for bash function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41416200/paths-with-a-does-not-make-sense-for-bash-function)

and this

[git fatal error Path with a does not make sense](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11914919/git-fatal-error-path-with-a-does-not-make-sense)

but neither of them seem to apply to me as my code does have modified changes and I do have a string guard around my variable.

I think this might be a product of my lack of familiarity with bash.

This is what I've tried,

```
function push(){
    BR=`branch | grep \* | cut -d ' ' -f2`
    git commit -am "$BR" " $1"
    git push origin "$BR"
}
```

The first line is using another command I have that shortens git branch to just branch, so I don't need to add 'git'

I've also tried removing the string around the "$BR" and just keeping it as $BR, which gives me the same error.

I'm getting an error with the commit that says

**fatal: Paths with -a does not make sense.**

But I know I have modified files that are already tracked by git (by running git diff) so am a bit confused as to why this is showing up

When I try removing the " $1" and keeping everything else the same it works, so I think it has to do with my actual commit message?

Comment: You are missing "git"  `BR=`git branch | grep \* | cut -d ' ' -f2``

Comment: How are you calling your function, i.e. what is the value of `$1`?

Comment: @EncryptedWatermelon I have another function that shortens git branch to just branch - will edit the question so others know

Comment: @0x5453 I am calling my function like this push "commit message"

Comment: At least, with Git 2.22, this error will be easier to debug: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55884451/6309

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're specifying the branch name as the commit message, and your commit message as a filename. Git is reacting to the fact that you are saying "Commit all files but only this file".

If you want to specify both the branch name and your message as the commit message, you have to pass them as a single argument:

```
git commit -am "$BR $1"
```

Comment: yup just got it as you posted. Thanks! Will check as correct in 4 min

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the docs for `git commit` (`git help commit`), when you add the `-m` flag, it expects the next argument to be the commit message.

```
-m <msg>, --message=<msg>
    Use the given <msg> as the commit message. If multiple -m options are given, their values are concatenated as separate paragraphs.
```

Therefore, `git commit -am "$BR" " $1"` is incorrect, since it would interpret your branch name as the commit message, and then all remaining args as some path specifier.

Try this instead:

```
function push(){
    local br=`branch | grep \* | cut -d ' ' -f2`
    git commit -a "$br" -m "$1"
    git push origin "$br"
}
```

Comment: Actually the branch name needs to be a part of the commit message (one of the reasons I'm trying to do this -- sick of forgetting and needing amend previous commits)

Comment: I figured it out with your help. I changed the line to ```git commit -am "$BR $1" ```

Answer (score 0):

The commit message is just **one argument** so try as follow:

```sh
git commit -am "$BR $1"
```